# Trying to refresh my coding. Palindrome excercise giving me an issue. Googled my error but cant fix it.

Tags: c++, string, oop, c++11, palindrome

I'm working on a c++ exercise and honestly knowledge on strings is a little foggy and probably why this isn't working. I've forgotten a lot syntactically but I have a good foundational understanding of OOP in general. Just trying to get back into the swing of things. Also I know my consistencies are weird with the std:: and then omitting it at places like cin haha. Just messing around.  Thanks for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string reverse(std::string s);
using namespace std;

int main(){

        std::string s;
        cin>>s;

        std::string n = reverse(s);
        if(n == s){
                std::cout<<"plindrome"endl;
        }
}


string reverse(string s){

        int n = s.length();

        for(int i = 0; i<n/2; i++){
                swap(s[i], s[n-1-1])
        }

        return s;

}
```

Comment: So what's the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string reverse(std::string s);
using namespace std;

string reverse(string s) {

    int n = s.length();

    for (int i = 0; i<n / 2; i++) {
        swap(s[i], s[n - i - 1]);
    }

    return s;

}

int main() {

    std::string s;
    cin >> s;

    std::string n = reverse(s);
    if (n == s) {
        std::cout << "plindrome" << endl;
    }
}
```

just fixed the swap line so it should be s[i] and s[n - i - 1] and syntax error while printing

Answer (score 0):

```
swap(s[i], s[n-1-1])
```

Look carefully at the second argument.